# Does the $\limsup$ of the average of random variables belong to the tail $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability

Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent random variables, and let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. For each $i$, let $\mathcal{G}_i=\sigma X$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_i$. Define $\mathcal{T}_n=\sigma(\cup_{m>n}\mathcal{G}_n)$: we can think about it as the information generated by all the "trials" after $n$. Lastly, define $\mathcal{T}=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\mathcal{T}_n$ : we can think about it as the information about the remote future.

Prove that $\{\limsup_n \frac1n S_n > b\} \in \mathcal{T}$

**My attempt**

Since $\limsup_n \frac1n S_n = \inf_{m\ge1}\sup_{n>m}\frac1nS_n$, we have that

$\{\limsup_n \frac1n S_n>b\} = \{\sup_{n>m} \frac1n S_n>b \ \ \forall m \in \Bbb{N}\} = \cap_{m=1}^{+\infty}\{\sup_{n>m} \frac1n S_n>b\}$.

Now fix an arbitrary $m \in \Bbb{N}$. The event $\{\sup_{n>m} \frac1n S_n>b\} \in \mathcal{T}_m$ as it is a function of $(X_{m+1}, ..., X_n)$. In addition, $\mathcal{T_m} \subseteq \mathcal{T_{m-1} \forall m \in \Bbb{N}} $. So, the event $\cap_{m=1}^{+\infty}\{\sup_{n>m} \frac1n S_n>b\} \in \cap_{m=1}^{+\infty}\mathcal{T_m} = \mathcal{T}$.

I am not sure my solution is correct, and if it is, I hope it can help someone. Any comment is appreciated!

Comment: If $Z_\ell$ are rvs we have
$$\{\inf_\ell Z_\ell>b\}\subseteq \cap_\ell \{Z_\ell >b\}$$
However the reverse inclusion is not true in general: choose $Z_\ell=b+1/\ell$ as a counterexample.

Comment: @Snoop it helps almost completely, I just can't prove the equality $\{\limsup_n \frac{S_n}n > b\} = \{\limsup_n \frac{X_k + ... + X_n}n$ for any $k\}$. Of course it is obvious intuitively, but I can't prove it.

Comment: I may address that point as an answer here. Are you interested?

Comment: Yes I am, that would be great! It is just the point I am missing.

Comment: let me know if need more details or if you're not convinced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will address your question in the comments. We suppose all rvs take real values. Let $\omega \in$ lhs. Then
$$b<\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}\leq \underbrace{\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq\ell\leq k}X_\ell(\omega)}_{=0}+\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k<\ell\leq n}X_\ell(\omega)$$
for any $k$ so lhs $\subseteq $ rhs. Now let $\omega\in $ rhs. Then for all $k$:
$$\begin{aligned}b&<\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k<\ell\leq n}X_\ell(\omega)=\\
&=\limsup_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}+(-1)\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq\ell\leq k}X_\ell(\omega)\bigg)\leq\\
&\leq\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}-\underbrace{\liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq\ell\leq k}X_\ell(\omega)}_{=0}\end{aligned}$$
So rhs $\subseteq $ lhs.